# Using `optimize` to solve for X in an equation in R

Tags: r, function, optimization, equation

Below, I wonder how to find the value of `x` which I expect to be about `.2`?

```
f = function(x, y = 0.07925971) pnorm(x) - pnorm(0) == y

# Tried:
optimize(f, c(-4,4))

# Tried:
uniroot(f, interval = c(-4,4))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

If you want to use `optimize` anyway, you should reformulate your objective function first, e.g.,

```
> f <- function(x, y = 0.07925971) abs(pnorm(x) - pnorm(0) - y)

> optimize(f, c(-4, 4))
$minimum
[1] 0.2000078

$objective
[1] 3.058234e-06
```

---

## Closed-form Solution

I guess you can have a closed-form solution for `x` using `qnorm`, so, no need to use `optimize` or `uniroot`

```
> f <- function(y = 0.07925971) qnorm(pnorm(0) + y)

> f()
[1] 0.2
```

Comment: Your closed-form solution is much better than any other solution, how could I have missed it?

Comment: Your closed form seem to malfunction for `y >= .5` but `optimize()` seems to produce some form of result in that case (`3.99995`). Any idea which one (closed form or `optimize`) is working correctly?

Comment: @SimonHarmel I think you should trust in the closed-form solution other than `optimize`, since the valid domain of `qnorm` should be `[0,1]`, it is right that we have no solution in the case of `y>0.5` since it is beyond the domain. When you use `optimize`, you will see that the resulting `$objective` is not close to `0` if you have `y>0`, that means you didn't really solve it.

Answer (score 3):

It's with `uniroot` that you will solve the problem but you have to change the function.

```
pnorm(x) - pnorm(0) == y
```

is equivalent to

```
pnorm(x) - pnorm(0) - y == 0
```

And the problem becomes

```r
f <- function(x, y = 0.07925971) pnorm(x) - pnorm(0) - y

uniroot(f, interval = c(-4,4))
#> $root
#> [1] 0.2000004
#> 
#> $f.root
#> [1] 1.697321e-07
#> 
#> $iter
#> [1] 6
#> 
#> $init.it
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> $estim.prec
#> [1] 6.103516e-05
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

Maybe it's not worth the trouble but function `newtonRaphson.basic` in package `VGAMextra` accepts the function's derivative as an argument. And the root, if found, is more accurate. In this case it gives two extra digits.

```r
f <- function(x, y = 0.07925971) pnorm(x) - pnorm(0) - y
fprime <- function(x) dnorm(x)
intercept <- function(x0, y0, slope) y0 - slope*x0

r <- uniroot(f, interval = c(-4, 4))
r2 <- VGAMextra::newtonRaphson.basic(f, fprime = fprime, a = -4, b = 4)

print(rbind(numeric_derivative = r$root, symbolic_derivative = r2), digits = 16)
#>                                   [,1]
#> numeric_derivative  0.2000004354845417
#> symbolic_derivative 0.2000000014343624

curve(f, -4, 4)
abline(h = 0, v = 0)
# the two tangents to the target point are almost 
# overplotted, only one line is displayed
abline(a = intercept(r$root, r$f.root, fprime(r$root)), b = fprime(r$root))
abline(a = intercept(r2, 0, fprime(r2)), b = fprime(r2))
# now the target point, the function's root
points(r$root, r$f.root, col = "red", pch = 19)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>